# ASP.NET forms-based authentication denies access to login page too

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a simple test application for demonstrating forms-based authentication in ASP.NET Webforms. 
Here is my web.config file:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear" >
          <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
          <user name="daniel" password="daniel"/>
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>    
    ....
    ....
</system.web>
```

But I got "**Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration**" even for "**Login.aspx**" page.

How can I resolve this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are denying all unauthenticated users to the entire application by having `<deny users="?" />` in your web.config.

Add something like...

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

after the `</system.web>` in your example above to allow all users access to the `Login.aspx` page.

Comment: I added it, but got the same error. I'm testing it on Visual Studio 2017, does it matter??

Comment: First thing would be to try isolate and create a [small stand-alone repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run locally to repro the issue. If you can put one together, publish it on GitHub and post the link here and I'll look into it.